# Error while using spring-data-elasticsearch : 3.1.0.M3

Tags: spring, maven, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm getting an error for the `ElasticsearchRepository` using the below `pom.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.raj</groupId>
  <artifactId>standalone-elastic-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>standalone-elastic-example</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <elasticsearch.version>6.2.2</elasticsearch.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
      <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No id property found for class com.raj.standaloneelasticexample.model.Employee!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.raj.standaloneelasticexample.StandaloneElasticExampleApplication.main(StandaloneElasticExampleApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No id property found for class com.raj.standaloneelasticexample.model.Employee!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No id property found for class com.raj.standaloneelasticexample.model.Employee!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchEntityInformationCreatorImpl.getEntityInformation(ElasticsearchEntityInformationCreatorImpl.java:52) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:67) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:73) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:298) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

[image: Elasticsearch]

Version : 6.2.2 so spring-data-elasticsearch : 3.1.0.M3 ([Ref : Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch))